# ClassNotFoundException after rebooting tomcat with liferay

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet

I have deployed liferay's portlets on my tomcat 6.0.29. Every time, when the server is restarting I see in my logs this exception:

> 08:19:14,255 ERROR [PortletBagFactory:93] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wkpl.portlet.ics.acts.Controller
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wkpl.portlet.ics.acts.Controller
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:90)
>       at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(PortletHotDeployListener.java:436)
>       at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:230)
>       at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:97)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:111)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:185)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:40)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletContextListener.doPortalInit(PortletContextListener.java:101)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:63)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:53)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletContextListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextListener.java:57)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

If I delete all files in two folders: ...\tomcat-6.0.29\conf\Catalina and ...\tomcat-6.0.29\work and then, after rebooting, I redeploy portlets, everything is fine.

Liferay version: 5.2.9.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this happen when you hot-deploy in the running server? Or when starting&deploying the already installed portlets?

Comment: It happens when liferay starting with already deployed portlets.